# Will 'beer snobbery' be a problem?

Tags: discussion

[image]

[Reddit source.](http://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/1mtw52/beer_preference_between_novice_and_expert_drinkers/)

This image demonstrates that 'expert' drinkers tend to rate stronger tasting beers higher.

I'm inclined to think that the same is going to happen here, with lagers being dismissed.

Do you think this is likely to be a problem for this SE?

Comment: This site isn't about *Rating* beers. It's about asking and answering questions *about* beer.
I'm not sure what the concern is here.

Comment: Eeeeh, I'm not sure that's what that chart *really* shows - at least in terms of causation. Most of the top rated beers come from very small breweries with limited resources. Producing lagers requires resources that a lot of small breweries just aren't interested in investing in. Put another way: it just so happens that all the interesting stuff is happening in a particular market segment these days, but trends shift.

Comment: I personally am a fan of high gravity porters. I also dislike hoppy beers. I am hoping to be pleasantly surprised one day. However, I will gladly try any beer you set in front of me. I feel this keeps me well versed in beer and allows me to talk about beer more completely. Hopefully our community will adopt the same attitudes and rather than snubbing a weaker ale/lager, discuss and learn from one another.

Comment: Is this chart saying there's at most a 0.5 star, or 10% difference between expert ratings and novice ratings?  That doesn't seem so bad.

Comment: @brian nearly one full star actually, as the graph goes from -.5 to .5, with points plotted as low as -.5 and as high as +.4.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz That's a delta for individual beers.  It's showing that an expert may rate Bud Light 0.2 stars lower or Firestone 0.4 stars higher, but on average no one beer is being rated with a difference more than 0.5.

Comment: DERP. I r bad at statistics and graphs and math and stuff. STAY IN SKOOL KIDS. I DIDNT AND THIS IS WHERE IT GOT ME.

Comment: "Reddit source", eh? Reddit has a URL pointing into BusinessInsider's image hosting, and a bit of sleuthing traces us to the original paper, [From Amateurs to Connoisseurs:
Modeling the Evolution of User Expertise
through Online Reviews](http://i.stanford.edu/~julian/pdfs/www13.pdf), from some Stanford computer scientists. I am a big fan of original sources.

Comment: @Grohlier `Remember, we're trying to make beer more classy!` I think you might need to get rid of me then.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz no need for the taunting.

Comment: @grohlier you do realize I'm mocking myself, right?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz it seemed like it was directed at the user asking the question the way I read it. Written communication does not always come across as intended. Sorry.

Comment: Nope. I was acknowledging that I was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem. And your graph has nothing to do with snobbery.

There are indeed some excellent lager beers out there. However, it is also among the lagers that you find plenty of low-quality beers. And these beers are sold globally. Hence they are widely known and also well known to novices.

The quality IS higher among the strong beers and it is among the strong ones that you find the world's best beers. That's a fact and your graph shows exactly that. And these strong high quality beers are not necessarily known to novices.